# Laravel Mix VueJS production page blank

Tags: vue.js, nginx, laravel-mix, laravel-7

After long frustrating hours of research I finally found the cause for my Laravel7 VueJS (within blade templates) application running on nginx throwing a blank screen. Yet I lack the explanation or correct config.

When I accessed any route it would be seen for around 200ms and then switch to a white screen without any errors in `npm run prod` config.
Body tag would be completely empty (it looked uncommented in the inspector)

```
[...]
<body>
<!-- -->
</body>
[...]
```

Funny enough (sarcastically speaking) on page reload the login page would work normally but after accessing any other route it would revert to the behaviour described above.

After switching to `npm run dev` the console threw the following error:

> [Vue warn]: It seems you are using the standalone build of Vue.js in an environment with Content Security Policy that prohibits unsafe-eval. The template compiler cannot work in this environment. Consider relaxing the policy to allow unsafe-eval or pre-compiling your templates into render functions.

and

> EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: `"default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'"`.

Which made me realize my nginx security config which I generated using the fabulous [Tool provided by DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/nginx) included the following line:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
```

After removing and restarting nginx everything works and looks as it does on my dev environment.

From what I get I now theoretically make my site vulnerable to XSS attacks but I do not fully understand what the option does or if it is safe to run without it with these circumstance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The CSP header just lets your browser know what sources of JS are allowed. However, it is really a backup plan - what causes XSS is some code on your system that would render unauthorised JavaScript.

For example, the comment boxes on Stack Overflow allow me to enter the following text: `<script src="http://evilserver.com/malicious.js"></script>`. Stack Overflow know what they are doing, so they make sure that what is rendered is HTML, and not a literal `<script>` tag. Thus, you need to make sure you take the necessary care when rendering **user supplied content** and you will be OK (in general you do this in your output layer, not when accepting/storing input).

If you accept HTML input from users (as Stack Overflow does) then you have to be especially careful to allow only certain tags, and to ensure that any JS vectors are blocked up. So, the following text:

*is actually in an `<i>` tag, which is rendered literally in the web app*

That one is OK, since it is safe. You do need to make sure that any attributes are carefully checked, and any invalid markup is rejected. These can also be the source of security problems. This is a complex enough problem that, if you need users to be able to input HTML, you should not attempt to filter it yourself. Use a well-tested and well-regarded library instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that helps. Although it still leaves me with a `?` for why Vue was not properly compiled when this was active. Since I used it within Blade in its own container it seems as if Laravel Mix does not precompile the templates but include JS on the fly not using `localhost` but the original domain which NGINX flags as XS thereby causing the browser to raise the flag. Is that theses correct?

Comment: I probably can't help on that @onewaveadrian, I don't do Vue.